# EIN : Width of output cells in notebook

Tags: ein, jupyter

I'm using [ein](https://github.com/millejoh/emacs-ipython-notebook) to view and work with Jupyter Notebooks.

I'd like to be able to set the cell width to that of the window so that text wraps as little as possible.  In a browser this can be done with...

```
from IPython.core.display import display, HTML
display(HTML("<style>.container { width:100% !important; }</style>"))
```

..but since this isn't HTML and doesn't work under EIN in Emacs.

Nothing in the [docs](https://millejoh.github.io/emacs-ipython-notebook/) suggests a way of controlling this.

Any pointers to documentation on how to do this or suggestions would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Pandas is sufficient, try:

```
pd.set_option("display.width", 120)
```